# Changing a form based add to textbox based

Tags: c#, forms

In my form, I have a quiz which loads questions and people are supposed to answer them. In one of the forms behind user authentication, they are able to edit answers and questions. I also wanted them to add their own, and this was done on a seperate form.

Instead of opening a new form, I'd like for the user to remain on the current form, and add a record based on information from the textbox located on the same form. How can I do this?

```
    private void addAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newRecord = myDataTable.NewRecord();
        EditDialog edit = new EditDialog(newRecord);

        if (edit.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(newRecord);
            currentRecord = myDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(newRecord);
            DisplayRow(currentRecord);
            UpdateDB();
            myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
        }
        edit.Dispose();
    }
```

[image]

Although it's not my form, this is the example I was working off. I have a form with one textbox, and the `addAnswer` button, with the code above. I thought there's no use for it, since it can be probably done on the same form.

In the previous form, I load the database, tables, and DataGridView. I also have a textbox which selects current loaded record/answer from DataGridView. I want to be able to use the same textbox as source for adding a new record.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or something, it is hard to visualize what you are trying to accomplish and where it is currently broken.

Comment: You could use a UpdatePanel with multiple Panels for each form and show and hide the relevant panels based on what the user is doing? EDIT: Ignore this, I thought this was for web.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Ok now there is an image its a little clearer, you could just add the relevant textboxes to a hidden form and overlay this on top of the textboxes you want to hide.  Its quite a messy solution.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you have already functioning input fields, and you want your button to, instead of modifying an existing entry, add a new one. I must be missing something because it seems like you already have all the code you need to accomplish this, just put your working "add" code from the other form in the new "add" event handler and use the existing input fields. Please let me know what I am missing and I would be glad to answer/help.

Comment: No, no. I have two forms, one main and another one opens the one I have the code for above. I want it to take the `Word` from the textbox on the first form, not the second.

Comment: So the essential question is, how to "pass" that value from the first form to this one?